# Efficient way to sort an array by one key, but list the array by another key?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, performance

I have an array that is structured like this:

```
[{ name: "Aardvark", count: 9 }, 
 { name: "Apple", count: 12 }, 
 { name: "Banana", count: 4 }, 
 { name: "Carrot", count: 6 }]
```

I would like to display the contents of the array to the user (mapping each item to a div), sorted by count, and then alphabetically, such that the the above array should always maintain the following sorted order and be displayed like this:

```
[{ name: "Apple", count: 12 }, 
 { name: "Aardvark", count: 9 },  
 { name: "Carrot", count: 6 },
 { name: "Banana", count: 4 }]
```

So, that's easy enough. Just sort call something like:

`arr.sort((a, b) => b.count - a.count || a.name.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.name.toLowerCase()));`

The issue is that I *also* need the ability to determine if a given string is in the collection. For example, I would need to test if `Carrot` exists in the collection.

Normally I would use some sort of array filter function, but the arrays are very large (many tens of thousands of elements), and the naive solution is too slow. Also, there are several of these types of collections, and if possible I would like to avoid having to maintain multiple collections that I would have to manually keep in sync with one another.

Is there a way to elegantly solve this?

Comment: what do you like to do, if found?

Comment: @NinaScholz There's a set of items that I would like to test for the existence of. If any of them are found in the larger collection, when I map them to a div, I make them red instead of grey (lol).

Comment: isn't it a part of data representation? not a part of sorting?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I suppose ideally it's sorted in some way so that rendering the list of items to the DOM is fast enough as it is currently O(nk)

Comment: @RyanPeschel couldn't you just use a dictionary with the name as key?

Comment: @Christian: I had that idea as well, but then the complexity burdens shifts to the displaying to the user. I have to then on-the-fly generate an array sorted by `count -> name`. Because iterating the map wouldn't have the items sorted by `count -> name`

Comment: If you do the compare within the sort callback you'll end up comparing some items more than once. Though I guess you could technically set a rarity value (or whatever that other item list represents) within the sort callback, but is there a reason this needs to happen at run time?

Comment: @JayB Yeah it's because it's an interactive list in React where users can add and remove items in real-time.

Comment: Where are you getting your data from? If you have tens of thousands of elements, then storing them in a single array in memory and trying to do any operations on them is going to be a performance bottleneck. Common solutions I've seen involve using databases and/or designing api's and interfaces around pagination. If this is all happening client-side then you might be able to get away with using [indexeddb](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API)

Comment: Storing tens of thousands of items in an array in the browser should be fine. I just need to have O(log(k)) operations on it most likely

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to render the elements?

Comment: You will need to maintain the category entries as object keys. When an item leaves a category just remove it from the object. If that needs to happen in more than one place then that spaghetti logic needs to change before it turns into a food fight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to find a specific name in a big array, and you have performance issues, why don't you use the name as the key in a dedicated object like this:

```js
const arr = [{ name: "Apple", count: 12 }, 
 { name: "Aardvark", count: 9 },  
 { name: "Carrot", count: 6 },
 { name: "Banana", count: 4 }];

// Initialize the object using the name as the key

const res = arr.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
        (accumulator[currentValue.name] || (accumulator[currentValue.name] = [])).push(currentValue);
        return accumulator;
    }, {});

// Keep the object in sync

const handler = {
    set: function(target, property, value) {
        if(!isNaN(property)) {
            if(res[value.name]) {
                const index = res[value.name].indexOf(target[property]);
                if(index > -1) {
                    res[value.name].splice(index, 1, value);
                } else {
                    res[value.name].push(value);
                }
                
            } else {
                res[value.name] = [value];
            }

        } 

        target[property] = value;
        return true;
    }
};

const proxy = new Proxy(arr, handler);

// Use the proxy instead of the array in your whole application

proxy.push({
    name: "Mango",
    count: 13
});

console.log(proxy);
console.log(res.Mango);

proxy[0] = { name: "Apple", count: 13 };

console.log(proxy);
console.log(res.Apple);

proxy.push({ name: "Apple", count: 14 });

console.log(proxy);
console.log(res.Apple);
```

Comment: I mention this in the OP. Having to maintain a separate object and manually keeping it in sync with the array is extremely error-prone. I'd very strongly like to avoid it if possible, because the array is changed in many places throughout the code base (and there are multiples of them). It's already complex enough.